# Does exercising help to treat varicosis?

Tags: exercise

Does exercising help to treat varicosis? Which exercises do you suggest me to do? They are at the beginning phase. It is difficult for an outsider to recognize them unless he inspects my legs carefully.

Comment: How bad are they, what are your own experiences, any relevant information you might have to add?

Comment: They are at the beginning phase. It is difficult for an outsider to recognize them unless he inspects my legs carefully :)

Comment: @ahmetozgul - consider adding your comment above to your question instead, as it's relevant to receiving an appropriate answer to your specific question. People answering often don't read the comments and jump into an answer without all the information they need.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do to increase your circulation will help with varicosis. According to [varicose-help.com](http://www.varicose-help.com/varicose-veins-exercise.html), exercises such as walking, bicycling, and swimming will not only help to prevent varicosis, but also deep-vein thrombosis and spider veins.

[Getridofthings.com](http://www.getridofthings.com/get-rid-of-spider-veins.html) also suggests exercise as the number one way to get rid of varicose and spider veins, followed immediately by maintaining a healthy body weight. Excess fat is known to reduce circulation, which in turn adds to the problem of varicosis. For worse cases that a healthy lifestyle alone won't recover, they also suggest sclerotherapy, laser surgery, or traditional surgery.

Additionally, you shouldn't wear any restrictive clothing (unless recommended by a doctor) such as tight pants or socks with a tight band, as these will also reduce your circulation. In the articles I've cited, they also suggest sitting with your legs uncrossed, or elevating your legs above your heart when resting.

Comment: Also, many yoga inversions, such as [shoulder stand](http://www.yogajournal.com/practice/598), are reputed to prevent varicose veins.